# Part of the code in the child process spawned by fork() is skipped

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I use `fork()` to spawn a child process to run some code, but I found that in the child process, some code like `printf("child is running");` below will not run, and when I remove the sentences in `switch()`, it will run rightly, I can't understand why this will happen.

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if(pid == 0){
        int execl_status = -1;
        printf("child is running");  // this will not run

        switch(cmdIndex)
        {
            case CMD_1:
                execl_status = execl("./cmd1","cmd1",NULL);
                break;
            case CMD_2:
                execl_status = execl("./cmd2","cmd2",NULL);
                break;
            case CMD_3:
                execl_status = execl("./cmd3","cmd3",NULL);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid Command\n");
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Change the `printf` line to `printf("child is running\n");`. Without the `\n`  `printf` doesn't flush `stdout` straight away and thus it may seem as if has not been executed. Otherwise I cannot see another reason why the child proc would not be running. Have you also checked that `fork()` didn't return `-1`?

Comment: @Pablo Thanks , this works for me, could you add a answer and I will close this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, change your `printf` line to

```
printf("child is running\n");
```

When you don't use `\n` at the end of the format string, `printf` usually doesn't flush `stdout` straight away and so it may seem as if nothing has been executed.

If you don't want to print the newline (for whatever reason), you could also flush `stdout` yourself:

```
printf("child is running");
fflush(stdout);
```

I see no other reason as to why it appears not to be running. Also don't forget to check if `fork()` returns `-1`, perhaps your user account has reached the limit of forked processes.